# Proving cofactor of product of matrices is equal to product of cofactor of matrices from a given representation of cofactor

Tags: matrices, tensors

I have been solving problems in "The mechanics and thermodynamics of continua" by Gurtin M.E., Fried E., and Anand L. The initial chapters of the book discuss basic tensor algebra of second order tensors.

One of the exercise problem for cofactors $()^{c}$ (section 2.11, problem 8) ask us to prove
$$(\mathbf{ST})^{c}=\mathbf{S}^{c}\mathbf{T}^{c}$$

using following definition or representation for cofactor
$$\mathbf{A}^{c} = \left[\mathbf{A}^{2}-(tr\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A}+\frac{1}{2}[(tr\mathbf{A})^{2}-tr\mathbf{A}^{2}]\mathbf{I}\right]^{T}$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a second order tensor; $(.)^{c}$ represents cofactor of (.); $(.)^{T}$ represents transpose of (.); $tr\mathbf{A}$ is trace of $\mathbf{A}$; $\mathbf{I}$ is the second order identity tensor.

P.S. I am aware of other proofs using $$\mathbf{A^{c}}=det(\mathbf{A})\mathbf{A^{-T}}$$
$$\mathbf{A^{c}}(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{Au}\times\mathbf{Av}$$

I have been trying out this problem since last few days but no success. Any help/hint would be great.

Comment: Query: is the underlying vector space $3$-dimensional?

Comment: Because in that case the definition is obviously just a complicated way of writing $(\det A) A^{-T}$. (Cayley Hamilton).

Comment: Yes, the underlying vector space is $3$- dimensional.

Comment: I could have used Cayley-Hamilton but book did not cover this in or before this section. So I think I am not supposed to use it.

Comment: I agree that the exercise seems to be to do it without CH. But it seems to me to be perverse to give a definition of $A^c$ that depends on on the dimension. As a matter of principle I'd refuse to do the exercise. ;-)